# How do I use a typed factory to resolve components that take parameters when using convention-based registration?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, conventions

Windsor's [docs](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md#resolving-with-arguments) say we can pass parameters in `TypedFactory` method calls and those parameters will get passed to the constructor of the type the factory is creating:

> You can also use methods that take parameters from the caller to resolve components. The argument you pass in, will be passed on to the container's resolution pipeline.

How does this work when using convention-based registration? I'm getting an exception when validating that there are no missing components and that my configuration is correct, saying that the type I want to pass to my constructor has not been registered.

For example, take the following code:

```
public interface IWatcherFactory : IDisposable
{
    IWatcher GetWatcher(ImportTarget importTarget);
}
```

which is registered with `container.Register(Component.For<IWatcherFactory>().AsFactory());`

```
public class FolderWatcher : WatcherBase
{
    public FolderWatcher(ImportTarget importTarget, ILogger logger, IClock clock, IFileSystem fileSystem)
        : base(importTarget, logger)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

where `WatcherBase` is

```
public abstract class WatcherBase : IWatcher
{
    public WatcherBase(ImportTarget importTarget, ILogger logger)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

which are registered with `container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IWatcher>().WithServiceAllInterfaces().LifestyleTransient());`

Now other questions and answers [say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30075551/1492861) the parameter names need to match for this to work, which mine already do.

This is the exact error I'm getting:

```
'FolderWatcher' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'ImportTarget' which was not registered.
```

I think the problem is that there's nothing telling Windsor that the dependency on `ImportTarget` exists because of the convention registration, but I can't be sure.

I also have a component selector which looks like this:

```
public class WatcherFactoryComponentSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        var config = arguments.FirstOrDefault() as ImportTarget;
        if (config == null)
        {
            return base.GetComponentName(method, arguments);
        }

        return config.WatcherFullyQualifiedName;
    }
}
```

which is registered like so: `container.Register(Component.For<ITypedFactoryComponentSelector>().ImplementedBy<WatcherFactoryComponentSelector>());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question covers two related but separate topics. I'll answer them in turn.

### Why is Windsor complaining about the missing `ImportTarget` dependency?

This doesn't have anything to do with how you register your components, be it by convention, one by one or (please don't) with XML.

Keep in mind Windsor is erring on the safe side and it doesn't assume you will **only** ever get a dependency on the `FolderWatcher` by using the typed factory method.
It tries to work with what it's got - that is, it looks into the components it does know about, and upon realising it doesn't have one for `ImportTarget` it produces this message.

Notice this is not an error, but more of a warning. It's there to draw your attention to the fact that if you were trying to take a direct dependency on `FolderWatcher` directly, you'd fail.

Now (referring to your own answer), registering a `Component.For<ImportTarget>()` will make Windsor shut up about it, but I'm guessing (without seeing the rest of your code) a plain `ImportTarget`, like one you'd get by `new ImportTarget()` isn't very useful, without the `WatcherFullyQualifiedName` properly set. So that is masking the problem rather than fixing it.

### What's the correct way of hooking up the component selector to the typed factory?

That's an easy one - you've done the right thing here.
Personally, unless you're using it for other factories elsewhere, I wouldn't even bother registering the `WatcherFactoryComponentSelector` in the container, but go `.AsFactory(cfg => cfg.SelectedWith(new WatcherFactoryComponentSelector()))`, but that's a minor point.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems all I needed to do is register `ImportTarget` with the container, which seems to have done the job.

```
container.Register(Component.For<ImportTarget>());
```

I also needed to change how I registered my `IWatcherFactory`:

```
container.Register(Component.For<WatcherFactoryComponentSelector>());
container.Register(Component.For<IWatcherFactory>().AsFactory(cfg => cfg.SelectedWith<WatcherFactoryComponentSelector>()));
```

**Disclaimer:** I have no idea if this is the *correct* way to do it, but right now it works so I'm using it until it presents any other issues.